# String array in C with garbage characters

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str[50];
    int i, alpha, digit, spec;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        // check for alphabets
        if (isalpha(str[i]) != 0)
            alpha++;

        // check for decimal digits
        else if (isdigit(str[i]) != 0)
            digit++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%d %d", alpha, digit);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm still learning and I know this might be easy for others..
the alpha counts the unnecessary/garbage values in the array. how do I get rid of it?
It should get the numbers of alphabets and digits in the string that I entered.

Comment: " how do I get rid of it?" - get rid of what? Provide a test data set and expected results.

Comment: The problem is not your string, the problem is that you did not initialize `alpha` and `digit` variables to zeroes.

Comment: Building on  @aragaer : doesn't your compiler generate warnings for this code?

Comment: `for (i=0;i<=50;i++)` will print everything in the array not only the characters that were read earlier. It will also access the array out of bounds on the last iteration because of the `<=`.

Comment: @nicomp: FWIW, neither `gcc` nor `clang` generate any warnings for this code unless run with `-Wall` (in which case only `clang` catches the uninitialized variables).

Answer (score 1):

```
int i, alpha, digit, spec;
```

defines four, *uninitialized* variables. Their values are *indeterminate*.

In particular, `alpha++` and `digit++` perform arithmetic with these indeterminate values, producing indeterminate results.

Initialize these variables to zero.

```
int alpha = 0;
int digit = 0;
```

---

`fgets` returns `NULL` when it fails - you should check for this.

Additionally, `fgets` may not populate your array entirely, but

```
for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}
```

always iterates through through the entire array - and then one extra, out-of-bounds element due to the off-by-one error (this invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). `<= 50`, should be `< 50`). Any values not populated by `fgets` will be indeterminate as well.

`printf("%c", str[i]);` can simply be moved inside the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `alpha` variable only accounts for the actual letters in the string entered by the user, but you must initialize `alpha` and `digits` to `0` to get the proper count. As defined in the posted code, they are unintialized, thus have indeterminate values.

Note also these remarks:

- you should test if `fgets` returns `NULL`, indicating an empty file or an unlikely read error.
- `for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {` goes one step too far. You should use `i < 50`.  Beware also that any characters after the null byte have indeterminate values.
- `char` arguments to `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` should be cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid potential undefined behavior on platforms where `char` is a signed type.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[50];
    int alpha = 0, digit = 0;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            // check for alphabets
            if (isalpha((unsigned char)str[i]))
                alpha++;
            else
            // check for decimal digits
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)str[i]))
                digit++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d %d\n", alpha, digit);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize alpha and digit. Here's the code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str[50];
    int i, alpha = 0, digit = 0, spec;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        // check for alphabets
        if (isalpha(str[i]) != 0)
            alpha++;

        // check for decimal digits
        else if (isdigit(str[i]) != 0)
            digit++;

        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%d %d", alpha, digit);
    return 0;
}
```